# 501 Multiple parameters to HELO not allowed

Tags: email, smtp

I'm sending out automated emails to some users and I get this error message back on undeliverable emails. The strange thing is that it's for only one domain (*@t-online.de).

What multiple parameters does it mean?

(Strangely, I'm also getting bounced by another domain *@gmx.de for multiple users stating "User is unknown {mx063}".)

Is this related to DNS PTR records? The email server I am using has only recently been set up.

Comment: What implementation of SMTP are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using SmarterMail 6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFCs governing the SMTP protocol state that the HELO statement should have only one value.

```
HELO mailer.example.com
250 mailer.subdomain.example.com Welcome, mailer.example.com, glad to meet you
MAIL FROM: postmaster@example.com
[...]
```

If the HELO statement has a space in it for some reason, some mailers will see that as something extra and puke on it. Others will just ignore it.

Comment: Cheers for that sysadmin1138.

Comment: The `MAIL FROM` command in your example is not syntactically valid. (Though many mail servers are forgiving enough about syntax errors to accept it anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

.... just incase anyone else has the same problem, you have to go into Admin and set the HELO property to your domain.

Comment: This answer is of no use unless you tell us what email server you're using

Comment: ... SmartMail 6.9 ... as in the comments above.